# Is there any harm in making everything a component?

Tags: reactjs

Even if it's not reusable? I am having difficulty understanding what should be a component and what shouldn't. So, I was thinking maybe making everything a component. For example, a `<img />` tag wrapped in `<NavBarImage />` Component?

Comment: Passing things down everywhere will get annoying if everything is a component.

Comment: What about using context or redux?

Comment: If you're already using them, sure, but if not, they add some boilerplate

Comment: In fact this is a good practice. As long as these components are going to be reusable. And this how you achieve the separation of concern.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would like to break some part into new component to make it reusable to other components or when your component has such high complexity(doing many things different) that it makes more sense to break down into smaller components.

you are talking about the first scenario. create some atomic component like a img tag. that's perfect acceptable to create a design system for your project to reuse through your project. Like, you can have a `Typography` element, you may define some basic custom props that can change how it looks and consume in different components.

now, if you want to create such a specific component that's not reusable I don't see the point. you are creating two or three files ( `NavBarImage.js`, `NavBarImage.css`, `NavBarImage.spec.js`), then you have to import it to `NavBar`. it wouldn't serve the purpose to make it reusable, and in a large project you'll face yourself lost in a sea of pointless components.